# SolcError: An error occurred during execution

Tags: solidity

This is my first attempt at Solidity.

I want to create a contract for each `Patient` and store several variables/information regarding the specific patient.

What does the traceback mean and how do I rectify the problem?

```
# Solidity source code
>>> compiled_sol = compile_source(
...     '''
...     pragma solidity >0.5.0;
...
...     contract Patient {
...
...         string public location;
...         string public pain_type;
...         string public intensity;
...         string public frequency;
...         string public pain;
...         string public psychosocial;
...         string public life;
...         string public better;
...         string public worse;
...
...
...         function setLocation(string memory _location) public {
...             location = _location;
...         }
...         function setType(string memory _pain_type) public {
...             pain_type = _pain_type;
...         }
...         function setIntensity(string memory _intensity) public {
...             intensity = _intensity;
...         }
...         function setFrequency(string memory _frequency) public {
...             frequency = _frequency;
...         }
...         function setPain(string memory _pain) public {
...             pain = _pain;
...         }
...         function setPsychosocial(string memory _psychosocial) public {
...             psychosocial = _psychosocial;
...         }
...         function setLife(string memory _life) public {
...             life = _life;
...         }
...         function setBetter(string memory _better) public {
...             better = _better;
...         }
...         function setWorse(string memory _worse) public {
...             worse = _worse;
...         }
...     ''',
...     output_values=['abi', 'bin']
... )

# retrieve the contract interface
>>> contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()

# get bytecode / bin
>>> bytecode = contract_interface['bin']

# get abi
>>> abi = contract_interface['abi']

# web3.py instance
>>> w3 = Web3(Web3.EthereumTesterProvider())

# set pre-funded account as sender
>>> w3.eth.default_account = w3.eth.accounts[0]

>>> Patient = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)

# Submit the transaction that deploys the contract
>>> tx_hash = Patient.constructor().transact()

# Wait for the transaction to be mined, and get the transaction receipt
>>> tx_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

>>> patient = w3.eth.contract(
...     address=tx_receipt.contractAddress,
...     abi=abi
... )

>>> location_hash = patient.functions.setLocation('Head').transact()
>>> location_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(location_hash)

>>> type_hash = patient.functions.setType('Headache').transact()
>>> type_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(type_hash)

>>> intensity_hash = patient.functions.setIntensity('2').transact()
>>> intensity_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(intensity_hash)

>>> frequency_hash = patient.functions.setFrequency('4').transact()
>>> frequency_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(frequency_hash)

>>> pain_hash = patient.functions.setPain('Aching').transact()
>>> pain_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(pain_hash)

>>> psychosocial_hash = patient.functions.setPsychosocial('Depression').transact()
>>> psychosocial_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(psychosocial_hash)

>>> life_hash = patient.functions.setLife('Sometimes').transact()
>>> life_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(life_hash)

>>> better_hash = patient.functions.setBetter('Lifestyle changes').transact()
>>> better_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(better_hash)

>>> worse_hash = patient.functions.setWorse('Smoking').transact()
>>> worse_receipt = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(worse_hash)
```

Traceback:

```
SolcError: An error occurred during execution
> command: `/root/.solcx/solc-v0.8.14 --combined-json abi,bin -`
> return code: `1`
> stdout:

> stderr:
Error: Function, variable, struct or modifier declaration expected.
  --> <stdin>:53:5:
   |
53 |     
   |     ^
```

Comment: In which function did you encounter this issue?

Comment: @Kerry99 That was the full traceback. I don't know where the issue occurred.

Comment: @melolilili I'd recommend to use an interactive IDE, like remix, until you familiarize with the language and tools. It will make much easier the cycle edit/compile/fix and repeat. The contract is missing the closing `}`.